# Pytest Testing Structure imports

Tags: python, pytest

I want to test using `pytest`. As I have read, it is good practice to have the following structure:

```
project/
  home.py
  tests/
    test_home.py
```

In my file `test_home.py` I have:

```
import pytest
```

How can I import `home.py` to test it?

Comment: The trick is to run your tests from the `project` folder. Then you can just use `import home`.

Comment: I tried your trick, went to my `project` directory and ran "pytest" in the bash. It found the test_home.py but it returned that it couldn't find home. Could it be that I'm inside a virtualenv?

Comment: Oh I found out how, I will write the answer below, your trick works but I needed to have a __init__.py in my test directory. Thanks @KlausD.

Answer (score 0):

It order to run pytest with a project structure as mentioned above, you need to have a `__init__.py` file inside the tests directory. Also make sure to run pytest from the project directory.